# Apache - htaccess how to block a GET request URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to block ALL access to URLs such as:

```
/services/login.php?action=clientlogin&user=K8YcWKOZ&password=UzTXhhn5
/services/login.php?action=clientlogin&user=m4eQ97We&password=xxAz6I8Z
```

Basically I want to give 403 ERROR to all URLs containing:`action`, `&user` and `&password`

I have tested:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /services/login.php\?action=clientlogin&user=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(user|password).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

AND:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /services/login.php\?action=clientlogin&user=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(user|password).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

But it fails to block access.

How can I block access to this URLs via htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?action=[^&\s]*&user=[^\s&]*&password=[^&\s]* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```